# Symfony 4 doctrine sqlsrv how to get output from stored procedure?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4, sqlsrv

I'm working with Symfony 4 and I'm trying to get the output from stored procedure but with doctrine it doesn't work.
If I use PDO it works. Why?

This is my code with doctrine:

```php
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();
$out = 1;            
$sql = 'EXEC SP_INSERT @IdTipoSuceso = ?, @Idprestador = 1, @Descripcion = 1';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $out, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

doctrine.yaml

```yaml
parameters:
        # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
        # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
        # environment variables are not available yet.
        # You should not need to change this value.
        env(DATABASE_URL): ''
    
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # configure these for your database server
            driver: 'sqlsrv'
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
```

And this is my working code with pdo:

```php
$pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=db', 'user', 'pw');
$query ='EXEC SP_INSERT @IdTipoSuceso = ?, @Idprestador = 1, @Descripcion = 1';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$out = 1;
$stmt->bindParam(1, $out, PDO::PARAM_INT | \PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 200);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Comment: $pdo = $entityManager->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection(); will give you the actual PDO connection.  I poked around a bit for a stored procedure example using the DBAL connection.  Best I could come up with is: https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.8/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.html  But the PDO work around should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to use `fetchAll`?

Try something like this:

```
$query = 'exec INTAK_NOWY_KONTAKT @id_kontrahenta = ?, @nazwisko = ?, @imie = ?, @tel = ?, @e_mail = ?, @id_kontaktu = ?';

$params = array(
    $id_kontrahenta, $nazwisko, $imie, 
    $tel, $e_mail, $id_kontaktu
);

$types = array(
    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, 
    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT
);

$con = $this->entityManager->getConnection();

return $con->executeQuery($query, $params, $types);
```